# Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [X.X.X.X]. Assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permissions

Tags: networking, linux-networking, centos7, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have a Zabbix configuration problem here in the company a few days ago. I'm having this error on the hosts page in the Settings portion. I have already done several tests, being:

1. Agent and Server Ports Release (Firewall Disabled)
2. I changed the settings of agent.config and server.config.
3. I disabled SELINUX.

If you can help me thank you, I only need this communication so I can proceed with the finalization of the installation.

> Error: Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [X.X.X.X].
>   Assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permissions.

I already looked for solutions in google but I did not find answers

**UPDATE:** 
I noticed that the server apparently has some network problem. I have managed to install normal zabbix using yum in Centos 7. However, the server is taking too long to ping google.com and is missing the settings in the resolv.conf file.

I do not know what this network problem can be, I'm a beginner in linux and I'm having a bit of trouble correcting this without having to configure a new server.

**UPDATE 2:**
I identified that the server did not contain the google DNS (8.8.8.8) configured in: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` so I added this registry and it solved the network problem, now it's ping google.com , before of this was only the internal DNS of the company. But the initial problem still persists and I think there may be some relationship with network configurations

Comment: Your configuration of the agent itself, and the host on the Zabbix server would be helpful. Otherwise it's just blind guessing.

Comment: Here's a Zabbix server and agent configuration:
[Server config](http://txt.do/d3i6f)
[Agent config](https://textuploader.com/d3i67)

Comment: Run your agent in debug mode, it will greatly help you to find out what's wrong.

Comment: The log file was generated with debug level 5: [LOG LINK](http://txt.do/d38cv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few attempts, I identified that Zabbix Agent was in a different version of the zabbix server version. After making the change and leaving both versions the same, it was possible to communicate with Agent

Answer (score 0):

Error is in agent config `SourceIP=192.168.17.197` is same as `Server` but this should be IP addrees of the client for outgoing traffic. Try comment this out or use client IP addres instead.

Comment: I tried to make this configuration in the agent commenting the SourceIP, restarting the zabbix agent and the server. The same error continued, in the "Settings > Hosts" screen, the "ZBX" is in red with the same message


Perhaps a failure is occurring when the server connects to this agent, I have identified this message in the log, I do not know if it is generic: `1436: 20181130: 105232.029 Message from 192.168.17.197 is missing header. Message ignored`.

Comment: Log of zabbix_server: `27435:20181130:104645.390 cannot send list of active checks to "127.0.0.1": host [DI-VZBX-197] not found`

Comment: but `127.0.0.1` is localhost, it should be something like `192.168.17.XXX` do you have `127.0.0.1` somewhere in the config?

Comment: This address 127.0.0.1 was the one that was configured on Zabbix_agentd.conf on the server. Even changing to the IP of the server it continues with the same error. But this agent is the only one that communicates with the server (I think it's because it's local).

The log that displays this error is the same server log. The agent I am trying to communicate (192.168.17.184) is a windows 10 and it does not have any configuration with 127.0.0.1, in the config of the server it also does not have the 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

do Tail -f /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log

Note down the first IP , 
now open agent config file
in front of

```
Server = <TAIL LOG IP>,127.0.0.1
ServerActive= <TAIL LOG IP>,127.0.0.1
```

Once you add these IP, zabbix agent will be sync and run.